# UserService retrieves wrong user after logout

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication

I get CurrentUser from UserService

```
 UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser().getEmail()
```

It works when. But when I logout, UserService still return same email.

Comment: Is this on the deployed app or locally?  Are you using Google Accounts for login (or federated login) ?  Make sure you have logged out of Google fully e.g. go to gmail or some other Google service and make sure you're not logged in there.

Comment: @planetjones, I deploy it on GAE and I made sure that I logout from Google.  I use Google account from specific domain (not gmail.com).

Comment: Just clear your browser cookie and try.

Comment: Yeah I can only back up what @Abdul Kader says - I have had some strange behaviour with GAE and its authentication, clear all cookies and close the browser down, then reopen it

Comment: @Abdul Kader, @planetjones With cleaning cookies it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're logging in by the usual means for GAE, your browser will end up with two session cookies - one for Google and one for the app.

If you also log out by the usual means (the logout URL from `create_logout_url`), then both cookies are deleted.

However, if the user browses away from your app to some other Google service and logs out of Google from there, then the cookie for your app isn't deleted (at least, not for me in Firefox). I'm not sure that it even can be - once the browser is away from your app, quite possibly it won't allow Google sites to touch your app's cookies in any way.

The fix *should be* to provide a logout link in your app, and for the user to log out using that. If you're already doing that, then I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: Thanks. I used to logout user by redirecting on http://www.google.com/accounts/Logout . Actually, I wan't to synchronize login session with Google as you describe. I think I can implement this by deleting some cookies per each request, but I hope that there is other convenient way.

Answer (score 1):

That answers everything. It seems that though you might have already logged out of google service, your browser was still maintaining a cookie for google service. That's why it was throwing the same user email again..